# Libs for complex animation of groups of objects in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

Are there any libraries for animation groups of objects in as3?

I need something like this: for example, I specify an array of images and creates the animation of all objects in the array - fireworks, the spiral vortex, 3D rotation, undulating, etc. Tweenlite and other libraries not fit, because there is no pattern complex motion.

I need to quickly apply complex animation paths to the set of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particle systems, such as Flint Particles may be inline with what you are citing:

Flint Particle System
http://flintparticles.org/

Examples
http://flintparticles.org/examples/logo-firework
http://flintparticles.org/examples/firework
http://flintparticles.org/examples/firework-display-3d
http://flintparticles.org/examples/catherine-wheel